# Angular 2: Deleting the record from an array of objects fetched from REST API

Tags: angular

Editing the question: I am trying to delete the selected record from an array of the objects fetched in JSON format from REST API. I am not able to delete the records using Array methods like splice(). To use the Delete() method of HTTP, the unique ID for each record is needed. But the problem here is in the API provided, there is no 'ID' information for the records. Please see attached image to view how the data is coming.

here is my code:

tasks.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { TasksService } from '../tasks.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tasks',
  templateUrl: './tasks.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tasks.component.css']
})
export class TasksComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private tasksService : TasksService) { }
  @ViewChild('newTaskForm') newTaskForm;
  tasks : any;
  data : any = {};
  taskData: Array<string>[];
  taskInfo;
  newData: Array<string> = [];
  subscription: Subscription;
  title: string;
  ngOnInit() {
      this.tasksService.getData()
      .subscribe(data => { this.taskData = data; console.log(data) })
  }

  onTaskSubmit(data) : void {
    this.newData.push(data);
    this.newTaskForm.reset();
  }
  deleteRow(rowNumber: number){
      this.newData.splice(rowNumber, 1);
      this.taskData.splice(rowNumber, 1); 
  }

}

tasks.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class TasksService {
  private apiURL = "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/angular-task-e7f39/databases/(default)/documents/tasks";
  public newTaskSubject = new Subject<any>();
  tasksInfo$ = this.newTaskSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: Http) { }
   getData(){
     return this.http.get(this.apiURL)
     .map((res:Response) => res.json());
   }
   addTasks(data){
     //data.title = "hello";
     this.newTaskSubject.next(data);
   }

  
}

//tasks.component.html (part of html where i have added the delete function and rowindex)

<table>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of newData; let rowIndex = index">
            <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="deleteRow(rowIndex)">Delete</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

when I use the splice function here:
this.taskData.splice(rowNumber, 1); // it says splice() is not valid method for taskData.

Whereas it does work for "this.newData.splice(rowNumber, 1);" where newData is an array which stores the data entered by the user manually.
I am saving the array of objects fetched from API in taskData.
How can't I use splice method to delete the record from array of objects? What am I doing wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrotc.png)

Comment: your `taskData` isn't being initialized as an array, which explains why you're getting the `is not a valid method` error.

Comment: I have already tried that. It doesn't work. Please see attached image to the question. Is it not applying because its coming from an api? and I have to use http().delete or post method? But without Id how can it be done?

Comment: try to declare `taskData` like this `taskData: any[]`

Comment: I have already tried initialising taskData as an array of any. like shown above. It doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: tried this "taskData: Array<string>[]; "  the error has gone but the record isn't getting deleted. Do I have to try something else to delete the data fetched using HTTP service?

Answer (score 0):

as can i see on the screenshot you get an object where you have documents array, so you need get data from this array

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this.tasksService.getData()
      .subscribe(data => { this.taskData = data.documents; })
  }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.